# Where does Moodle 2.0 store files? In the database or in the filesystem?

Tags: database, linux, oracle, moodle

I'm planning on installing [Moodle](http://moodle.org/) in a server (using an Oracle 10.2 DB and CentOS 5.6).

Do I need to allocate a lot of space for the database?
Or the content of the courses will be saved in the filesystem and the database only stores "pointers" for the files?

Comment: I've created a proposal for a Stack Exchange website for Moodle users and developers. This question would be a perfect fit for it, rather than for Stack Overflow. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33861/virtual-learning-environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle stores (and has always stored) files in the filesystem. You can see that in [the sample configuration file](http://cvs.moodle.org/moodle/config-dist.php?revision=1.156&view=markup) there is an option for the "data root" directory (section 4).

Comment: Then, what is stored in the database? Links for the contents of the courses? Config settings?

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth: When talking about *uploaded files*, the database generally stores filenames and organizational ids. However, the Moodle database schema has **lots** of tables and pretty much everything but the files is stored in the database. Depending on your user count it may grow to be quite big quite fast; you just don't have to worry about the uploaded images, documents and media.